# Stop Updating mapView Location

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

How does one stop updating the location of the user once it has been loaded. Like stop the user location pin from continuing to move around and update. I still want the location icon there, but to stop updating. Already tried

`locationmanager.delegate = nil`
 `locationManager.stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()`

Answer (score 0):

you can use like below to stop updating location

```
locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

class Map: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate  
{

var mapView: GMSMapView?
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 40.7, longitude: -74.0, zoom: 4.0))
    view = mapView

    if (CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()){
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: locations.last!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: locations.last!.coordinate.longitude)

    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: center.latitude, longitude: center.longitude, zoom: 4.0);
    self.mapView?.camera = camera
    self.mapView?.isMyLocationEnabled = true

    let marker = GMSMarker(position: center)

    print("Latitude :\(center.latitude)")
    print("Longitude :\(center.longitude)")
    marker.title = "Current Location"

    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
}

}
```

In this if you want to stopUpdating locations after your location once then you need to write:-

```
locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
```